# Xamarin Emulator Crashes when opening camera

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin application and the emulator camera crashes when I launch the app.
I get the following error message

[image]

- I am using Visual Studio 17.7.1
- C#
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.3.2
- Xam.Plugin.Media 5.0.1 (For Camera)
- Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1269

Camera Opening Code Segment

```
var photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });
```

My Graphic Cards details:

- Intel (R) HD Graphics 530
- NVIDIA Quadro M2000M

Comment: You could try to reinstall the Android SDK. And test on another emulator with different version.

Comment: I mean error is pretty clear, your AMD drivers are broken. Despite, Your Graphic Cards are Nvidia, yet for some reason your emulator is trying to use AMD drivers. Try digging into that. Try selecting different Processor when creating an emulator.